# Reading from a CSV returns IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, import

I have a script that manages an employee database.  After adding an employee record and appending a CSV file with the data, I close the program.  Starting fresh, I try to import the CSV and it returns the error "IndexError: list index out of range."
After appending the csv and closing the program, I then open the csv using notpad++.  In the file, two additional lines are added.
Using a try - except block, how can I delete rows from the CSV file?
In the add_employee function, can anyone see why it's adding two additional rows?

```
def import_employees():
    with open('Employee_database.csv', 'r') as csvfile: #Opens the student answer file, and closes once finished
        employee_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        first_row = True
        for row in employee_reader:
            #Skip the first row with column names
            if first_row:
                first_row = False
                continue
            try:
                fullName = row[0] + ' ' + row[1] #Creates full name for dictionary key
                employeeList[fullName] = row
            except IndexError:
                del 

def add_employee(): #CPT 200: Functionality 1 part 1
        employeeFName = input("Please Emter the Employee #%d's First Name:" % num)
        employeeLName = input("Please Enter the Employee #%d's Last Name:" % num)
        employeeSSN = input("Please Enter %s %s's SSN (123456789):" % (employeeFName, employeeLName))
        employeePhone = input("Please Enter %s %s's Phone Number:" % (employeeFName, employeeLName))
        employeeEmail = input("Please Enter %s %s's Email Address:" % (employeeFName, employeeLName))
        employeeSalary = input("Please Enter %s %s's Salary:" % (employeeFName, employeeLName))
        employeeFull = employeeFName + ' ' + employeeLName
        print(" ")
        employeeInfo = [employeeFName.capitalize(), employeeLName.capitalize(), employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary]

        if (employeeFull and employeeSSN) not in employeeList.keys():
            with open('Employee_database.csv', 'a+') as employeeCSV:
                employee_writer = csv.writer(employeeCSV)

                employee_writer.writerow(employeeInfo)
        else:
            print('Employee is already in the database, please try again.')

        return employeeFull.upper(), employeeInfo
```

Comment: in your try block, before forming fullName, print out `row`. I suspect it's not what you expect. Otherwise, simplify your question, provide exact error (w/traceback).

Comment: Everything from `first_row` down should be indented to the right a level. You're closing the file before you even loop through its rows.

Comment: @pbuck The loop populates the correct data into the file, but it also adds two additional rows to the file. The full name line creates the dict key.

Comment: @J. Owens if the come closed, it wouldn't write at all to the file and definitely wouldn't add additional lines

Comment: Please simplify your question (you've asked three: Why IndexError, How delete rows, Why extra rows?). Second, provide executable code, your raw `del` after except IndexError is a syntax error. We're lazy, so the more you can help, the more we can. Finally, it basically works for me (after defining global `employeeList`), so ball's in your court.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, I ended up getting an A in the class